# Rails 3 problem with rake and bundler: rake aborted! Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I'm pretty new to RoR, I have a couple of working rails apps on my computer but I must have done something wrong because now I can't create new apps. The problem is when I do this:

$ rake db:migrate

I get this:

```
anarres@supakewl:~/prog/rails3/myapp$ rake db:migrate
(in /home/anarres/prog/rails3/myapp)
rake aborted!
Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0)
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
/home/anarres/prog/rails3/myapp/config/boot.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/anarres/prog/rails3/myapp/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/anarres/prog/rails3/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/ruby/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I definitely have Bundler 1.0.7 installed. I installed it by doing

$ sudo gem install bundler

and I'm guessing that could be the problem because I've read in a couple of places that you're not supposed to use sudo. But if I try to do that without sudo I get a permission error. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and Rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

Try sudo gem list just to ensure that bundler is there on your system.

Also, if you're using RVM, make sure you've installed it for the active VM - I've run into this a few times where I've switched to a different RVM, forgot to install bundler in the base gemset and fire off a task that then generated this error.